# C - Program crashes while using malloc

Tags: c, crash, malloc, xor-linkedlist

So I'm making a XOR linked list, and whenever I'm trying to allocate memory for a new node, program crashes. Here's my code for insert function:

```
void add(DataType value, XORList ** xlist)
{
    XORListNode * node;
    node = ( XORListNode* )malloc( sizeof (XORListNode) );
    printf("node memory allocated\n");

    if ((*xlist)->head->prevPNext == NULL && (*xlist)->tail->prevPNext == NULL) //XOR linked list is empty: [ H - T ] + N => [ H<->T<->N ] => [ H<->A<->T ]
    {
        node->prevPNext = (*xlist)->tail; //new element points to tail
        (*xlist)->tail->prevPNext = ( XORListNode * )( (uintptr_t)(*xlist)->head ^ (uintptr_t)(*xlist)->tail ); //tail points to head and new value
        (*xlist)->head->prevPNext = (*xlist)->tail;

        (*xlist)->tail->value = value;
        (*xlist)->tail = node;
    }
    else    //Otherwise: [ H<->A<->B<-...->X<->T ] + N => [ H<->A<->B<-...->X<->T<->N ] => [ H<->A<->B<-...->X<->Y<->T ]
    {
        node->prevPNext = (*xlist)->tail;
        (*xlist)->tail->prevPNext = ( XORListNode * )( (uintptr_t)(*xlist)->tail->prevPNext ^ (uintptr_t)node );

        (*xlist)->tail->value = value;
        (*xlist)->tail = node;
    }
}
```

This is definition of XORList:

```
typedef struct XORList
{
    XORListNode * head, * tail;
} XORList;
```

And this is definition of XORListNode:

```
typedef struct XORListNode
{
    DataType value;
    struct XORListNode * prevPNext;
} XORListNode;
```

I would also appreciate any other comments about the code, because I'm not yet that experienced with pointers.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: 1) don't cast the return value of `malloc()`. 2) check for the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer.

Comment: Tried omitting the cast. Crash remains during the malloc. Thanks about the checking for the success of malloc tip though.

Comment: Also, check `(*xlist)->head` for NULL before `(*xlist)->head->prevPNext`. same for others.

Comment: It is also good practice to avoid assuming that pointers and values are set, instead check return values and values are NULL before you use them, that way you catch errors early on. e.g. `assert( xlist != NULL );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `malloc` is not the problem of your implementation. You can test this by removing the entire body of the function except of the first three lines.

As Sourav Ghosh pointed out, the main issue is that you don't check if `xlist`, `*xlist`, `(*xlist)->head` or `(*xlist)->tail` is NULL before using those pointers in if-clause `if ((*xlist)->head->prevPNext == NULL && (*xlist)->tail->prevPNext == NULL)`.

So if you have an "uninitialized" list `head` and `tail` will be `NULL` (or if you've not set them to `NULL` they will be some value like `0xcccccccc` or something completely undefined) resulting in an access violation since your're trying to access an address which is not available to your application.

To fix this you have to handle the following case in your add function:

```
void add(DataType value, XORList ** xlist)
{
    XORListNode * node;

    if ((xlist == NULL) || ((*xlist) == NULL))
    {
        printf("INVALID INPUT (xlist)\n");
        return;
    }

    node = ( XORListNode* )malloc( sizeof (XORListNode) );
    if (node == NULL)   // always check return values
    {
        printf("FAILED TO ALLOCATE !!!\n");
        return;
    }

    if (((*xlist)->head != NULL) && ((*xlist)->tail != NULL))
    {
        /* your current implementation goes here */
    }
    else
    {
        /*
        ** no item within list, yet!
        ** - initialize head and tail attributes of *xlist
        ** - set node->prevPNext to NULL
        */
    }
}
```

Three more things:

- I strongly suggest to implement a zero function for your `XORList` structure which ensures that the `head` and `tail` members are NULL. Otherwise they are uninitialized and a check if they are NULL will not work and you're having access violations again.
- Why do you use a double pointer to `XORList` in function `add`? A single pointer is sufficient for the code you've posted.
- Since `malloc` may fail in some cases you should implement a return value for function `add`. Otherwise the caller is unable to know if adding was successful or not. I would simply return the value of `node`. If the function failed the return value is `NULL` or nonzero in case of success.

Comment: Thanks to you and Sourav Ghosh, the crash issue has been solved. Thanks for the tips too. :)